# Should data controllers return NSManagedObjects or NSObjects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, architecture, nsmanagedobject

I have several data controllers in my app. Each data controller is responsible to manage a certain part of the data. They can access CoreData, process the `NSManagedObject`s and make sure that all is thread safe by using `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` queues for `NSManagedObjectContext`s depending from which thread the caller is using the data controller.

It’s architected in a way that only the data controllers know about CoreData stuff like contexts, managed objects, fetch requests etc.

That implies that `NSManagedObject`s should not be returned by the data controllers. First to ensure that they can only be accessed by the correct context, which is only available in the data controller itself, and secondly to enforce the architecture that only the data controllers handle anything related to CoreData.

But what should the data controller return? Is it a good idea to create a `NSObject` copy of a `NSManagedObject`, copy all attributes and return that? It would make sense but it seems to me that this is not the ideal solution or even unnecessary.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you've given the right answer already in your question:

> It’s architected in a way that only the data controllers know about CoreData stuff like contexts, managed objects, fetch requests etc.

You should avoid to break your Core-Data-independent design by providing `NSManagedObjects` to the rest of your program. It's good and highly testable design to be independent from third-party frameworks - especially persistence frameworks. Therefore go with `NSObject`.

Also keep in mind that the persistence framework might change over the lifetime of your program. The business models rather do.

---

**Comment update**

To convert a `NSManagedObject` to a `NSObject` and vice versa you have to write your own marshaller/converter class. There are plenty of tutorials how to convert `NSManagedObject`s to a `NSDictionary` incl. relationships.

If faulting is really needed, you have to this on your own as well. But this - as performance optimization in general - should be the last topic on your list and only be on your list if you run into performance issues in production.

Comment: You're right, but is there an easy and save way to create a `NSObject`out of a `NSManagedObject`considering that there could be a complete child structure attached to an `NSManagedObject` attribute or even some faulted attributes?